# Any XMPP plugin for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, xmpp, chat

I'm looking for a XMPP library or plugin for my flutter project to build chat app.

I've tried looking at https://pub.dartlang.org searching for XMPP but no luck. 
Searched github and found this https://github.com/MaxHorstmann/dart-xmpp but unfortunately its a half cooked library which has stopped development.

Hope someone can share or recommend me a library or plugin for flutter/dart XMPP?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xmpp

Comment: @Najeeb this only works for android currently and still in development, but will follow this one in case they support iOS in future. Thanks anyway

Comment: How about https://pub.dev/packages/xmpp_stone, otherwise, you may need to create your own via https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Answer (score 1):

Yes friend there are 3 available as of now and I am listing them below and you can check them :-

> 1. flutter xmpp :- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xmpp
> 2. Xmpp stone :- https://pub.dev/packages/xmpp_stone
> 3. flutter xmpp
>    plugin :- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xmpp_plugin